# How to compare a cell with text to 2 columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I've tried and researched a lot, but somehow I can't find a solution to my problem:

There's A1:A50 containing various names (e.g. Bond) and B1:B50 also with names (e.g.James)(-> not necessarily in the surname/given name order, but that shouldn't matter). 
C1 contains a text like "Bangkok Mission, 14.3.15 - 16.3.15, James Bond, assassination, travel costs".
What I want to happen in D1 is to put an "X" if any name of A:A and B:B appear in C1.

So far it only compared A1 and B1 to C1. So any name in A2/B2 and following was ignored... anything else I tried failed completely.

Is there a way to make this happen?

Comment: You say you can compare only A1 or B1, can you update your question with how you did that?

Comment: I believe you can use the find() function to help out here.

Comment: Just to confirm, the values in A and B for a row must be treated as a pair (e.g., getting Sally Bond from A3 and B7 doesn't count)?

Comment: @fixer1234 Well, it doesn't have to be treated as a pair.. but it has to be found in both A and B.
Companys send me lists with their employees and with business trips. 
What I'm trying to find: employees in the recpient (that's easy) and the 'reference' field

Comment: @Jonno: I won't have access to the sheet until Sunday, but I'll try to recreate what I did in a test sheet

Comment: Not sure I understand your reply.  Do A and B contain first and last name, and a row = a person, so what you're searching for in C is a person defined by values from the same row in A and B?  Or are you mixing and matching names from A and B, so what you're searching for in C is any combination of any name from A and any name from B?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this Formula (it is a complicated one) in D1 write
=IF(AND(SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND($A$1:$A$50,C1,1)),1,0))>0,SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND($B$1:$B$50,C1,1)),1,0))>0)=TRUE,"X","") it is array Formula click Ctrl+Shift+Enter at the same time and drag it down to the last row in your data
A1:A50 and B1:B50 are column A and B where you have the Names